# Call an Android build-tool from an Eclipse "builder"?

Tags: android, eclipse-plugin, android-build

I've been asked to automate the process of building a 'secondary dex' that can be loaded by a `DexClassLoader`. The idea is that instead of manually exporting to a .jar file and then running the `dx` script to add `classes.dex` to a new .jar in the main project's assets directory, normal compilation of the secondary project would automatically copy a dynamically loadable .jar to the main project.

It does look like I can do this by marking the secondary project as an Android Library (so that it compiles to a .jar) and adding an Eclipse Builder that calls the `dx` script. I've got a bash script and a .launch wrapper for it that passes `${project_loc}/bin/${resource_name}.jar` to the script; if I place the bash script in the main project's root directory, `%0` tells me where to copy the loadable .jar.

Of course, `dx` is not on the path. I figured I'd do a `which adb` and then use `find` ... but `adb` is not on the path, either!

So, my question: Is there an Eclipse string variable that contains the location of the Android SDK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fwiw, I never did find "an Eclipse string variable that contains the location of the Android SDK". Instead, what I did was

1. Read the `dx` script and notice that it just passed arguments to `dx.jar`.
2. Add the most recent available `dx.jar` to my Builder project, and simply call it directly, from my Java code. The source was not hard to find. It turned out that the main `main(String[])` simply dispatched to one of several internal `main(String[])` methods, so I just called the right one directly.
3. Split my Builder into two pieces: a) a 'stand-alone dexxer' which is just a jar file that can be called from an ant action, and which calls into `dx.jar`; and b) an Eclipse Builder which contains the build control logic and a bit of Eclipse console code, and which calls into the stand-alone dexxer.

This worked fine. We figured that if Google ever released a `dx.jar` that somehow offered significantly better dexification, we could just rebuild the Builder with the new jar; this hasn't been an issue, yet.

Answer (score 0):

A coworker pointed out that `${project_classpath}` contains a path to `annotations.jar` in the SDK directory. That let me write this script:

```
#!/bin/bash

#####
##### Get the directory this script is running in.
##### We will write our output to ${client}/assets
#####

client=${0%/*} 

#####
##### Get the input parameter; calculate the output
#####

input=$1
output=${client}/assets/${input##*/} 

#####
##### Use the classpath parameter to find the latest dx script:
#####

# Turn : into \n
classpath=${2//:/\\n}

# Find the line that refers to annotations.jar
annotations=`echo -e $classpath | grep annotations`

# Strip the filename
path=${annotations%/*}

# There may be multiple copies. We get access time and path.
# We output : instead of \n because bash "Word Splitting" is complicated.
jars=`find $path -name dx.jar -printf "%A@ %p:"`
until [ "$jars" ]
do
  path=${path}/..
  jars=`find $path -name dx.jar -printf "%A@ %p:"`
done

# Turn : into \n
jars=${jars//:/\\n}

# We want the last accessed jar
sorted=`echo -e "$jars" | sort -nrk 1,2`

# Get the jar filename
last_used=`echo -e "$sorted" | grep -om 1 "/.*$"`

# Strip the filename
last_path=${last_used%/*}

# Find the dx script
dx=`find $last_path -name dx`
until [ "$dx" ]
do
  last_path=${last_path}/..
  dx=`find $last_path -name dx`
done

#####
##### Add classes.dex to input jar
#####

$dx --dex --keep-classes --output $output $input
```

Here's it's `.launch` file, with the project name and path redacted:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<launchConfiguration type="org.eclipse.ui.externaltools.ProgramBuilderLaunchConfigurationType">
<booleanAttribute key="org.eclipse.debug.core.ATTR_REFRESH_RECURSIVE" value="false"/>
<stringAttribute key="org.eclipse.debug.core.ATTR_REFRESH_SCOPE" value="${working_set:&lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;UTF-8&quot;?&gt;&#10;&lt;resources&gt;&#10;&lt;item path=&quot;/MAIN_PROJECT_NAME/assets&quot; type=&quot;2&quot;/&gt;&#10;&lt;/resources&gt;}"/>
<booleanAttribute key="org.eclipse.debug.ui.ATTR_LAUNCH_IN_BACKGROUND" value="false"/>
<booleanAttribute key="org.eclipse.ui.externaltools.ATTR_BUILDER_ENABLED" value="true"/>
<stringAttribute key="org.eclipse.ui.externaltools.ATTR_LOCATION" value="${project_loc}/../MAIN_PROJECT_DIRECTORY/secondary-dexxer"/>
<stringAttribute key="org.eclipse.ui.externaltools.ATTR_RUN_BUILD_KINDS" value="incremental,auto,"/>
<stringAttribute key="org.eclipse.ui.externaltools.ATTR_TOOL_ARGUMENTS" value="${project_loc}/bin/${resource_name}.jar&#10;${project_classpath}"/>
<booleanAttribute key="org.eclipse.ui.externaltools.ATTR_TRIGGERS_CONFIGURED" value="true"/>
</launchConfiguration>
```

Not exactly optimal, and definitely not something I can add to the source tree (we have people who use Windows for some reason) but a start: painful though some of the bash "Word Splitting" issues were, they presumably do pale next to the learning curve that will be involved in turning this into a 'proper' Eclipse plugin, in Java.